# Tracing a Nested java for loop

Tags: java, arraylist, nested-loops

The code segment is:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        count++;
        inner.add(count);
    }
    outer.add(inner);
}
System.out.println(outer);
```

I trace the loop like this:
when `i = 0`, inner will be updated to `[1, 2, 3]`. Hence the `outer` will be `[[1, 2, 3]]`.

When `i = 1`, `inner` will be updated to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. Hence the `output` which is `outer` will be `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`

However, when I run the program, the `output` is actually `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`.

Why is this so?

Thanks

I have edited the code

Comment: You are adding **the same** array each time.

Comment: The codes is completely useless. You are adding `inner` to `inner` all the time (which will not even compile, since `inner` is not an Integer and thus will not fit into itself), without adding something else to it. There are never any numbers added. So what you say doesn't fit your code. Fix your code.

Comment: why adding `inner` to `inner`? Please try to think atleast

Comment: I am sorry that I typed wrongly

Comment: is this increased the `inner` arraylist with `size` of 3 each Iteration like `[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Comment: @VikrantKashyap Initially I thought the code was doing stuff like what you said but the output is just [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]].

Comment: Are you aware that you're printing outer, but it's not used anywhere in the code.

Comment: @GoneWithTheFlow Have you got your answer ?? I have added a answer of your Question.. Thank you

Comment: @VikrantKashyap thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is Complete Working code what you try to print Exactly. Try this out.

```
     ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
     ArrayList<Integer> inner ;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            inner = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //each time new ArrayList<Integer> Need to Create. 
           for (int j = 1; j <= i*3; j++) {

               inner.add(j);
        }
          outer.add(inner);
      }
System.out.println(outer);
```

**Output** :

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Mistake that you do is You are not creating different object of `ArrayList<Integer>`  at each Iteration of Outer loop `i`. So, each and every time if you add the `int count` will be added to the same `object`.

eg:- In First Iteration when `i = 1` then `inner` loop will add `[1,2,3]` to the `inner` ArrayList.

In Second Iteration when `i=2` then `inner` loop again Initialize the previous `inner` ArrayList Object which already contains `[1,2,3]` Now you add `[4,5,6]` to it. So `ArrayList<Integer> inner` become `[ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ]`.

Hope got your mistake.